# From nested array to array of object

Tags: javascript, html

I have a nested array like this

```
array = [[1, 698],[32, 798],[69, 830],[95, 500]]
```

I want to have a function that return the result in this format

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        score: 698
    },
    {
        id: 32,
        score: 798
    },
    {
        id: 69,
        score:830
    },
  ..... the rest of the array
]
```

I did use a for loop but with no success, and I have no idea on how to aproach the situation.

```
for(var i = 0; i <= array.lenght ; i++){
    var obj={}
    var res = []
    res.push(array[i])
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify why this is not working: you re-create `res` in each iteration from scratch, so you don't push the mapped data to the **same** array each time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take the advantage of the power of the ES6 syntax:

```js
var array = [
          [1, 698],
          [32, 798],
          [69, 830],
          [95, 500],
        ];
var res = array.map(([id, score]) => ({id, score}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const array = [[1, 698],[32, 798],[69, 830],[95, 500]];
const result = array.map(([id, score]) => ({id, score}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `array.prototype.map`, `destructuring` and `shorthand object litteral`:

```js
var array = [[1, 698],[32, 798],[69, 830],[95, 500]];
var result = array.map(([id, score]) => ({id, score}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var sampleArray = [[1, 698],[32, 798],[69, 830],[95, 500]];

var finalJson = sampleArray.map(([id, score]) => ({id, score}));


// Final Result
console.log(finalJson);
```

Answer (score 2):

first you need a function that takes a 2 element array and returns an object

```
const objBuilder = arr => return { id: arr[0], score: arr[1] }
```

you will want to add error handling, but thats the basic idea.

Next you want to iterate over the array of arrays transforming each value (2 element array) into an object.  Thats called mapping over values, and js supports it natively

```
const arrayOfObjects =  array.map(objBuilder)
```

more about map function here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2):

The answers from a number of people suggesting `.map(([id, score]) => ({id, score}))` are great.  But if you have to do things like this often, you might want to write a reusable function to make this more declarative.  For that, something like this might work:

```js
const zipObject = names => values => names.reduce(
  (obj, name, idx) => (obj[name] = values[idx], obj), {}
)

const array = [[1, 698], [32, 798], [69, 830], [95, 500]]
console.log(array.map(zipObject(['id', 'score'])))
```

Note that you could also extend this to

```
zipAllObjects = names => listsOfValues => listsOfValues.map(zipObject(names))
```

and just call

```
zipAllObjects(['id', 'score'])(array)
```

Comment: i like your approach , but i am not sur if the the OP will be able to understand it

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif: Thanks.  You're quite possibly right, but I like pushing even slightly more functional approaches when possible.